# Laravel redirect back with input throws error "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4

I have a laravel form that uses input arrays with input elements structured like this:

```
{{ Form::text('parent_firstName[]', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'first name') ) }}
```

In my store method, I want to do some data validation and redirect back if the validation doesn't pass. My redirect statement uses the back method with input:

```
return Redirect::route('registration.create')
    ->withInput();
```

When I do this, I get the error:

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /var/www/app/views/registration/create.blade.php)

When I read the documentation, it looks like this would be the proper way to redirect back with the input so it fills back in the input data.

If I comment out the `->withInput()` I get no errors.

Any ideas of why it's throwing the error?

Comment: Did you work this out?

Comment: Yeah I did. The reason you can't return it with the `withInput()` is because Laravel assumes that the data being passed back in the `withInput()` method is going to be an array of strings, not an array of arrays. You basically need to pass it back differeently, e.g. `return Redirect::route('registration.create')->withArrayInput($input);` where `$input` is your request input. Then write javascript for your view that will take the `$ArrayInput` variable, loop through the arrays in it, and fill in the fields on the form. If the rows are created dynamically the js needs to do that too.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it (I'm having a *facepalm* moment), you can just create the rows dynamically through the view's php logic (`@foreach(@ArrayInput as $input) @foreach($input as $inputrow) ... @endforeach @endforeach`). I passed it through javascript because I already wrote the javascript object to create the rows dynamically, but it would have been easier to just have php create the rows if I knew there was an array of input arrays coming back to the file :/